# Clarification question about a common integral evaluated using residue theorem

Tags: contour-integration, complex-integration

In the evaluation of
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}\,dx\,,$$
you are to consider
$$\frac{1}{2}\Re{\oint_C \frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}}\,dz\,,$$
where $C$ is the usual semi-circular $R\rightarrow \infty$ contour in the upper half-plane. My question is why would you not just consider
$$\oint_C \frac{\cos z}{1+z^2}\,dz\,?$$
If you do, you get
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\left(e+e^{-1}\right),$$
instead of the correct
$$\frac{\pi}{2e}\,.$$
Why is that? I expect this to be a duplicate as I have seen two other people ask this question on another website, both with no response. If so, sorry.

Comment: How did you get the residue at $z = \mathrm{i}$?  I get that the residue is $\frac{-\mathrm{i}}{4}(\mathrm{e} + \mathrm{e}^{-1})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use $\cos z$ then the intergal over the semi-circular portion does not tend to $0$ as $R \to \infty$. You do not have control over $|\cos (Re^{it})|$.

[ Note that $e^{-R \sin t}$ is bounded by $1$ but $e^{R \sin t}$ is not bounded].

Comment: Oh I see, I was making the mistake of assuming $\lvert \cos{z} \rvert$ was bounded by 1 but with complex values that doesn't hold, correct?

Comment: Yes, No entire function is bounded. $\cos$ and $\sin$ are bounded on the real line but not on the complex plane. @HaleBays